# コンポーネントをクローンのように表示したい

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<html>
    <compornet-a></compornet-a>
    <compornet-a></compornet-a>
</html>

<template>
    <div class="contents">
        {{num}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                num: 0,  
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            testApi.then(
                (resolve) => {
                    this.num = this.num + 1;
                },
                (reject) => {
                    this.num = 0;
                },
            );
        }
    }
</script>
```

上記のように、同一画面に同一のコンポーネントを読み込む場合に
mountedのAPI処理が二度走るのを解消したいのですがどうしたら良いでしょうか？
extendを使用すると、templateを再定義しなければならないため避けたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compornet-a`を埋め込んでいる側のコンポーネントの`mounted`でtestApiを実行して、実行結果をpropsで`compornet-a`に渡せばよいのではないでしょうか?

Comment: 確かに...、めちゃめちゃシンプルな考え方ですね。